# Is there a proof of correctness for CPS translations into Appel's IR?

Tags: reference-request, continuations

The IR given in Appel's book ([Compiling with Continuations](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/compiling-with-continuations/7CA9C36DCE78AD82218E745F43A4E740)) is certainly well explored and battle-tested in production compilers. I have been able to find several works based on or inspired by it (either by Appel himself, such as [Shrinking Lambda Expressions in Linear Time](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/papers/shrink.pdf), or by other people, as this one by Kennedy, [Compiling with Continuations, Continued](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/compilingwithcontinuationscontinued.pdf)). However, I haven't been able to find any *proofs* that CPS translations into it are actually correct. By correct I mean computational adequacy: a term $e$ would halt in the source language's semantics if and only if its translation $[\![e]\!]$ would halt in the IR's semantics.

Is there a proof of that for any CPS translation into the IR? I'm particularly interested in finding references for Plotkin's CBN and CBV translations, but any one would be enough.

*Edit:* Clarifying, the point is that this IR requires that arguments are always variables, and is thus not closed under $\beta$-reduction. Appel's book gives a denotational semantics for it by interpreting it into ML, and Kennedy's paper gives a big-step machine semantics for it; Appel's paper on shrinking reductions suggests using function inlining as a semantics, and [Thielecke's PhD thesis](https://era.ed.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/1842/14533/Thielecke1997.Pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) gives an equational theory for it. All these notions are well-behaved with regard to each other.